# Should you perform feature scaling/mean normalization when predicting with a model?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, training

Should you also perform feature scaling/mean normalization when predicting with a model, that was trained and tested on with feature scaling/mean normalization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, testing data should follow the same preprocessing as the training data. Otherwise, testing data will have nothing comparable with what the algorithm learned, leading to (very) bad performances.

note: In Sklearn, the [Pipeline class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) helps you to respect the fundamentals of ML modeling like data leakage and applying the same transformations to train and test set.